# Unable to import package installed in develop mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools, distutils

**Directory structure:**

```
root/
-> setup.py
-> src/
-> -> package1/
-> -> -> __init__.py
```

**Content of setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='ptest',
    version='1.0',
    packages=['package1'],
    package_dir={'package1': 'src/package1'}
)
```

**INSTALL**

when I install the package using `python3 setup.py install`

I am able to import the *package1* using `python3 -c 'import package1'`

I could see file `ptest-1.0-py3.7.egg` added into `site-packages` and line `./ptest-1.0-py3.7.egg` added into file `site-packages/easy-install.pth`.

On unziping `ptest-1.0-py3.7.egg` contents are:

```
  inflating: EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO       
  inflating: EGG-INFO/SOURCES.txt    
  inflating: EGG-INFO/dependency_links.txt  
  inflating: EGG-INFO/top_level.txt  
  inflating: EGG-INFO/zip-safe       
  inflating: package1/__init__.py    
  inflating: package1/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc
```

So I am able to access package1, which is normal according to me.

**DEVELOP (Issue lies here)**

But when I install the package using `python3 setup.py develop`
or even when I use `pip3 install -e .`

I am not able to import the *package1* using `python3 -c 'import package1'`

I could see line `/path/to/root` added to file `site-packages/easy-install.pth` and another file `ptest.egg-link` in `site-packages`, contents of this file are:

```
/path/to/root
.
```

Also I could see `/path/to/root` is being added to the `sys.path`.

**Here is my question**: I want to make `setup.py` such a way that when I run it in develop mode, I should be able to import `package1`
some way that `/path/to/root/src` gets added to `sys.path` using setup.py.

Let me know if I am doing something wrong regarding understanding of setup.py.

**NOTE**: site-packages folder is inside virtual environment folder. I am using virtual environment for this.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you use `pip install -e .` to install your package in develop mode?

Comment: Yes it is same in this case also.